# How to trouble shoot test::unit errors?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a test that creates the following error:

```
1) Failure:
test_should_get_create(ProductRequestsControllerTest) [/Users/noahc/Dropbox/mavens/test/functional/product_requests_controller_test.rb:37]:
"ProductRequest.count" didn't change by 1.
<2> expected but was
<1>.
```

How do I trouble shoot this? Specifically, how can I get a more specific detailed error?

Here is my test:

```
 test "should get create" do
    sign_in(FactoryGirl.create(:user))
     assert_difference('ProductRequest.count') do
      post :create, product_request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product_request)
    end

    assert_response :success
  end
```

and here is my controller:

```
 def create
  cart = current_cart
  rows = CartRow.find_all_by_cart_id(cart.id)

  rows.each do |row|
    product_request = ProductRequest.new(params[:product_request])
    product_request.user_id = current_user.id
    product_request.product_id = row.product_id
    product_request.quantity = row.quantity
    product_request.save
  end

  redirect_to root_path 
 end
```

I believe the issue is that I don't have a cart defined. How do I create a cart that unit::test can see? I've tried using FactoryGirl to create a cart, but that didn't seem to work.

carts_factory.rb

```
FactoryGirl.define do

  factory :cart do
  end
end
```

Updated test:

```
test "should get create" do
    sign_in(FactoryGirl.create(:user))
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
     assert_difference('ProductRequest.count') do
      post :create, product_request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product_request, user: user.id, product: product.id)
    end

    assert_response :success
  end
```

and current_cart

```
 def current_cart 
      Cart.find(session[:cart_id])
    rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound 
      cart = Cart.create 
      session[:cart_id] = cart.id
      cart
    end
```

***Second Update***

I've updated the factories as you've suggested.

Here is what my test now looks like:

```
 test "should get create" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  cart = FactoryGirl.create(:cart_with_1_row)
  product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
  sign_in(user)

  product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
  assert_difference('ProductRequest.count') do
    post :create, { product_request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product_request, user_id: user.id, product_id: product.id, cart_id: cart.id) }
  end

  assert_response :success
end
```

Here's it in a test console:

```
irb(main):016:0> a = { product_request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product_request, user_id: user.id, product_id: product.id, cart_id: cart.id) }
=> {:product_request=>{:quantity=>10, :street=>"123 street", :city=>"Some City", :state=>"Iowa", :zip=>"13829", :user_id=>1, :product_id=>2, :cart_id=>1}}
```

Comment: you're missing a closing parenthesis on the sign_in(FactoryGirl. If that doesn't do the trick, let me know!

Comment: @Solomon, already fixed that. Sorry, I should have updated this post. Still a no-go.

Comment: Debug this code as you would any other. For example you say that you believe the issue is that the issue is that you don't have a cart, so stick some breakpoints or logging statements in or around the `current_cart` method to see whether or not that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, `CartRow.find_all_by_cart_id(cart.id)`, this is not good design. Much better when you ask Cart model for its row, for example: `rows = cart.rows`

I think the issue is that you don't have rows inside you cart.

As I see you store cart id in session but when you call controller in test you does not provide session. You need create cart and cart's rows and when store  cart_id in session before you call controller. **And it is important to merge current session and session with cart_id**. For example:

```
test "should get create" do
  user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
  cart = FactoryGirl.create(:cart_with_1_row)
  sign_in(user)

  product = FactoryGirl.create(:product)
  assert_difference('ProductRequest.count') do
    post :create, { product_request: FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:product_request, user: user.id, product: product.id) }, { cart_id: cart.id }.merge(session)
  end

  assert_response :success
end
```

Also you need update your cart and cart's row factories:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :cart do
    factory :cart_with_1_row do
      after(:create) do |cart|
        FactoryGirl.create(:cart_row, cart: cart)
      end
    end
  end

  factory :cart_row do
    cart
  end
end
```

I think your CartRow model looks like:

```
class CartRow < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cart
end
```

Comment: Yes, the cart and cart rows are created before calling the controller.

Comment: @NoahClark Could you please add code which create cart and cart's rows in your controller test before controller call?

Comment: See Second update above. Same issue, but I think we need to get the block off of submission. Is that correct?

Comment: I've dropped the blocks, but still no go. Appreciate your help so far.

Comment: Also, CartRow has `belongs_to :product` in it.

Comment: When you hit controller in your test you does not give its session. Look at my variant of test. My post call have 3 params - controller's action, params and session. Your post have only 2 params - action and params. I have tried to recreate your application and run your and my variants of test. My variant works.

Comment: @NoahClark I found what was the issue, I forget what devise store authentication information in session and when session set in test, the authentication information is not saved in session. I have fixed test and send you pull request. I check fixed test it pass in my environment. I hope it will pass in your environment now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem definitely seems to be coming from the cart.

If you don't want to deal with creating a cart in FactoryGirl (which I would recommend), you can just stub out the current_card in the test, and this would do the same thing.

However, mocking is much more complicated than creating the cart in FactoryGirl, and if you're planning on using this down the road, FactoryGirl is definitely the way to go.

Comment: See above. I have a carts_factory.rb, but all I am using is the ID from the cart essentially as an interface so the session in the browser and the server can agree and then store cart_rows in the db.